# The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property

Tags: node.js, selenium, webdriver, protractor

Local Environment :

> Windows 10
>
> Node v6.10.3
>
> Npm v3.10.10
>
> Protractor v5.1.2

**Issue Summary**

I am running Protractor for the first time (following this guide http://www.protractortest.org/#/tutorial) and the Protractor test runner is not executing properly. With Selenium running in the background via `webdriver-manager start` the following error (partial stack trace) gets thrown when executing the command `protractor conf.js`.

> The path to the driver executable must be set by the
>   webdriver.chrome.driver system property.  E/launcher - Process exited
>   with error code 199

According to the documentation found on GitHub (https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts), the path to the Webdriver can be specified in the configuration file which is what I did.

Below is an example, how my conf file looks like.

```
conf.js
----
exports.config = {
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
specs: ['todo-spec.js'],
capabilities: {'browserName': 'chrome'},
directConnect: false,
chromeDriver: 'C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_2.29.exe'
};
```

The same error is being thrown after updating the conf file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you try running it without mentioning the chromedriver path. When you run it you might get an error message(if not great) stating that chromedriver is not available in a particular path. Try updating your web driver and copy and paste chrome driver manually in that path.

Comment: run the command 'webdriver-manager status' from command prompt and see the chrome driver version

Comment: @santhoshkumar.  It seems to be running fine without specifying the path to the chromedriver.  

@SureshSalloju.  `webdriver-manager status` shows that chromedriver version is at version 2.29 which is the latest stable I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I threw a hail mary, reset my computer, and the issue was then resolved.  More specifically, the path to the chrome webdriver that was specified in the conf file fixed the error.  What I was running into was a persisted selenium process that failed to shutdown.  After killing the persisting selenium process via system restart, I was able to run the protractor test-runner successfully.